# Vtiger CRM REST API using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, vtiger

I am trying to create a Java wrapper for Vtiger REST API. I want to avoid the use of vtwsclib library because I could not find its Maven artifact. I want to use Spring `RestTemplate`. Actually, I don't understand why I need some special library to access REST API of a webservice.

First a got into problem with login process. Even when I followed the instructions from [this](http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html) link, I was not be able to retrieve `sessionName`. Finally, I resolved it after some research of vtwsclib library.

Next problem is with the retrieve operation. Even when I had `sessionName` and tried to retrieve some object by id with request (a ticket I can see in client app)

```
GET .../webservice.php?operation=retrieve&sessionName=xxxxx&id=xxxxx
```

I got:

> {"success":false,"error":{"code":"ACCESS_DENIED","message":"Permission to perform the operation is denied for id"}}

Last problem is documentation, even when I visited their wiki [Vtiger WIKI](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php) I could not find attributes of Ticket entity to create fields map.

So the work with this API is a bit painful for me. My questions are:

1. Is there some tutorial how to obtain sessionName using only Spring RestTemplate?
2. <strike>Why retrieve operation failed?</strike> update: bad id format
3. This is the main question. Is there some better documentation (tutorial, blog, file, ect.) for Vtiger REST API and descriptions of objects like Ticket?

Comment: which id format are you using?

Comment: the correct format is NNxNNNNN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also using Spring RestTemplate for Vtiger rest api.

For Retrieving details of record using REST API we need to pass id as `moduleId x recordID` (2x1234) format, otherwise it will give ACCESS_DENIED Error

Comment: I am out of the project, so I cannot try your suggestion. I will accept your answare then.